# Calculate number of days based on criteria

Tags: excel, date, if-statement

I need to calculate occupancy time for a population of migratory animals. Occupancy is defined as the period, in days, between the first and last sighting of an individual in a given year. A small example of the type of sighting data I am dealing with in Excel:

[image]

I need to be able to calculate the number of days between sightings within a year and not between the first and last sightings or between each sighting. I'm wondering if there is a way to do this with DATEDIF and IF statements.

EDIT: I am revisiting this analysis, as a specific problem as shown up. In order for my data to be correct, the formula needs to return a "1" if the animal was only seen once during a given year and a "0" if not seen at all. As it is presently, the formula returns a "0" if it was seen once or not at all.

Comment: Please explain this further: `I need to be able to calculate the number of days between sightings within a year and not between the first and last sightings or between each sighting.`

Comment: Please show a sample of what the correct output would look like.

Comment: I want to be able to determine the average number of days the animals are staying in the area in a given year.  Looking at examples from the sample data I have included:   Individual 11 would have 0 days between sightings for 2005 (since only sighted once), 6 days between first and last sightings 2007, and 0 in 2010. Individual 37 would have 12 days between sightings in 2000 and 9 days in 2001.  Does that help to clarify?

Comment: Yes. That's correct.

Comment: Oops. My apologies. I misread July as June for that individual. The correct number would be 40 days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way to do this by formulas, but I **really** don't recommend it!

Using "`max(if(`" and "`min(if(`" (a form of formula that's quite tricky to use - you must press [ctrl][shift][enter] when typing it in) as follows:

in cell K2 use the following formula:

```
=DATE(YEAR(MIN($B$2:$J$2)),1,1)
```

this sets the earliest year for your sightings

in cell L2, edit the cell, paste the following line, then press [ctrl][shift][enter]:

```
=IF(N(K2)=0,"",MAX(MAX(IF($B$2:$J$2<DATE(YEAR(K2)+1,1,1)-1,$B$2:$J$2))-MIN(IF($B$2:$J$2>=K2,$B$2:$J$2)),0))
```

you should see "{"  "}" surround the formula text. If you don't and get #VALUE, try again!

in cell M2 paste the following formula:

```
=IF(N(K2)=0,"",IF(MAX($B$2:$J$2)>DATE(YEAR(K2)+1,1,1),DATE(YEAR(K2)+1,1,1),""))
```

Format K2 and M2 as custom "yyyy" to show the year.

Now copy the range L2:M2 and paste to N2, P2, R2 and every second cell to the right as you like.

You should end up with pairs of cells showing the year, and the number of days between first and last sightings in that year, for each year from the earliest year to the last year in your data set.

Comment: Thanks Conor. But why would you not recommend this approach?

Comment: It's ugly! These "array formulas" are not highlighted much in standard Excel documentation, and are little used. The IF(..) construct is bizarre to most Excel users. They're confusing!